# Flate rate shipping is not showing

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

I am using magento 2.1.7. I have enable the Flat rate shipping but still it is nit showing.

Kindly can somebody help me for that

Answer (score 1):

Did you install any one-page checkout extension, try to disable that extension and check,

or check by clearing the Magento cache (`php bin/magento cache:flush`),
or if you have a multistore website, then check the store level shipping method configuration.

Comment: I got your point in multistore I cannot find price and enable field where can I find it